# Move text inside border

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to move the text inside fat border of my parent element. I am using material-ui and my component looks-like this:

```
   <List className={classes.root}>
       <Typography className={classes.fieldLabel}>Attach PDF</Typography>
             {/***SOME CODE**/}
  </List>
```

Style of the 2 elements (root and fieldLabel classes):

```
root: {
    width: "100%",
    maxWidth: 360,
    border: "3px solid #388FCE",
    marginLeft: "3%",
    maxHeight: 200,
    overflow: "auto",
    borderTop: "40px solid #388FCE",
    position: "relative",
  },


 fieldLabel: {
    transformOrigin: "0 0 ",
    position: "absolute",
    fontSize: "1rem",
    textTransform: "uppercase",
    letterSpacing: "3px",
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    color: "red",
    fontWeight: "bold",
  },
```

I am trying to move this Attach PDF sign inside border:

[image]

What I am doing wrong so the sign is still inside and not into border?

Comment: Instead of moving it into the border, set the background of the text to match the color of the border and make it span the width of the parent

Comment: alternatively you could set the top value to an negative number.

Comment: @YannickEich The sign is getting hide behind the border.

Comment: @szczocik This is one idea I would not reject if there is no other solution

Comment: This is not how to use borders. Instead use a container element like a `div` that has the color as its background color and place it at the top of your box.

Comment: you could set the top value to a negative and add z-index more the than border div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason to place that heading into the material-ui `List` element and force it into a border. Just wrap the `List` in a component that renders the header before the list:

```
const ListWithHeading = ({heading, classes, children, ...props}) => (
    <div className="list-container">
        <Typography className={classes.fieldLabel}>{heading}</Typography>
        <List classes={classes} {...props}>{children}</List>
    </div>
);
```

You can give the element that contains the `heading` a class to style it, e.g. give it a background color and make it full width.

Render it like that:

```
<ListWithHeading heading="Attach PDF">
    {/* list items here */}
</ListWithHeading>
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than trying to bend space and time to move the text up - simply remove the top border - and have the height and backgrounnd of the text to match the internded layout.

I have dodgied up your elements using classes - and it simply works. and no bending of space or time :)

```css
.root {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 360px;
    border: 3px solid #388FCE;
    margin-left: 3%;
    max-height: 200px;
    overflow: auto;
    border-top: none;
    display: block;
  }


 .fieldLabel {
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    background: #388FCE;
    font-size: 1rem;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    color: red;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: block;
    padding-left: 10px
  }
```

```html
<List class="root">
       <Typography class="fieldLabel">
        Attach PDF
       </Typography>
             {/***SOME CODE**/}
  </List>
```

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest you to use ListSubheader https://material-ui.com/api/list-subheader/

```
   <List 
      className={classes.root} 
      subheader={
        <ListSubheader className={classes.subHeader} component="div">
          Attach PDF
        </ListSubheader>
      }>
          {/*** Your List Items**/}
  </List>
```

And
add styles to it. eg:

```
subHeader: {
  background: '#388FCE',
  // other required styles
}
```